# Php Calculate percentage difference between two numbers

Tags: php

I am trying to find the difference of two numbers in percentage. The actual scenario is iam getting a total value of user data for this week and for last week. Now i need to see the performance difference in percentage with this weeks data and last weeks data. Following is my code which i am trying. But at times either any of the data will be zero and am getting an error "Division by zero". How to handle that?

```
$this_week_cust=$row["cust_count_new"];
$last_week_cust=$row["cust_count_old"];

$percentChange = (1 - $last_week_cust / $this_week_cust) * 100;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if `$this_week_cust` is zero and just set the change to 100%

```
$this_week_cust=$row["cust_count_new"];
$last_week_cust=$row["cust_count_old"];
if ( $this_week_cust == 0 ) {
   $percentChange = -100;
}
else {
   $percentChange = (1 - $last_week_cust / $this_week_cust) * 100;
}
```

Altough the change would be 0 if `$last_week_cust` was also 0, so perhaps

```
if ( $this_week_cust == 0 ) {
   $percentChange = ($last_week_cust==0)?0:-100;
}
```

Comment: I guess there is an issue when last weeks data is 1 and this weeks data is 0. With the current code its showing 100% which is incorrect.

Comment: I would have expected 100%, as it has fully changed, what would you expect the %age change to be?

Comment: Yes, as per the code its correct. It should be 100% but i am expecting something like -100 because last week it was more and this week it was less. So that in my code i have to mention the percentage in red color with a down arrow. I guess i need to check on that.

Comment: It would be easy enough to change in this case - just change the line to be `$percentChange = ($last_week_cust==0)?0:-100;` (so add the - in).  But you would have to check your existing calculation as well.

Comment: Thank you so much, its fine. Yes i will check the existing calculations.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will help you.

```
$original= 1000;
$current = 5;
$diff = $current - $original;
$more_less = $diff > 0 ? "More" : "Less";
$diff = abs($diff);
$percentChange = ($diff/$original)*100;
echo "$percentChange% $more_less agaist $original";
```

Comment: This worked for me, thanks. I used it like so:

function percent_change(int $firstFigure, int $secondFigure): int
{
    $diff = $secondFigure - $firstFigure;

    $diff = abs($diff);
    $percentChange = ($diff / $firstFigure) * 100;

    return $percentChange;
}

Answer (score 0):

try this

if `$this_week_cust!=0` that time only calculation will perform otherwise not do anything

```
$this_week_cust=$row["cust_count_new"];
$last_week_cust=$row["cust_count_old"];
if($this_week_cust!=0){
   $percentChange = (1 - $last_week_cust / $this_week_cust) * 100;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the desired result by checking `$this_week_cust`, if is it return zero, null or empty set $this_week_cust to 100;

```
$percentChange=100;
```

Comment: What about the rest of the calculation?

Comment: Should go with the same calculation.